# How to run many tags on Serenity BDD using maven?

Tags: java, maven, serenity-bdd

I have classes:

```
@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
@WithTags({@WithTag("myTag", @WithTag("myTag1"))})
public class Class1 extends BaseConfig {
//test impl
}

@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
@WithTags({@WithTag("myTag"), @WithTag("myTag2")})
public class Class2 extends BaseConfig {
//test impl
}

@RunWith(SerenityRunner.class)
@WithTags({@WithTag("myTag"), @WithTag("myTag3")})
public class Class3 extends BaseConfig {
//test impl
}
```

Usually, for running tests in all classes, I use the command: `mvn clean install -Dtags=myTag`

And for running tests in Class1, I use the command: `mvn clean install -Dtags=myTag1`

So my question is: which command should I write for running tests from Class1 and Class2 but tests in Class3 should not run?

Thanks a lot for the correct answers.

Comment: Solutions like: "mvn clean install -Dtags=myTag1,myTag2" or "mvn clean install -Dtags=myTag1 -Dtags=myTag2" or "mvn clean install -Dtags=myTag1 -DandTags=myTag2" does not working.

Comment: Could you try `mvn clean verify -Dtags="myTag1 or myTag2"`? https://serenity-bdd.github.io/docs/reporting/filtering_reports

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `mvn clean verify -Dtags="@tag1 or @tag2"`, I am running them from feature files(cucumber) and for me it is working with -Dtags.filter.cucumber